# How to generate Unique ID even when copying entries in sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm creating a simple script to generate Unique IDs every time someone add a new entry.

The problem I'm facing, is that sometimes people will add a new entry by copy pasting the whole row of another entry, and then editing it with the new information.

How can I add some logic so when someone copies the whole row, including the existing ID, the script checks that ID doesn't exist, or if it does ensure a new one is added instantly.

Below I included my script, which is functioning in [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z2nn5z3yvQkZUl9Z0ziMLOPXHQcHnu_gKWlW0eVRlKc/edit#gid=0). Here's how it works:

1. The script first checks where the "Headers" row is, so  it can be used for the ID generation function
2. Then will look to when the column F ("TITLE") is edited, and generate an ID in column A, using the two first characters of the column D ("CATEGORY") and a random number

Now if I copy paste one existing row, the ID will be duplicated. How can that be avoided?

```
function header(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0, iLen = values.length; i < iLen; i++){
    for (var j = 0, jLen = values[i].length; j < jLen; j++){
      if (values[i][j] == 'CATEGORY'){
        return i + 1;
      }
    }
  } 
}

function onEdit(evt) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 
  var headerRow = header();
  var rowMax = sheet.getMaxRows();
  var colMax = sheet.getMaxColumns();
  var col = 1; 
  var colNames = sheet.getRange(headerRow, col, 1, colMax).getValues();
  var launchIdEntry = '';
  var launchName = '';
  var productName = '';

  for (var i = headerRow + 1; i < rowMax; i++){
    
    launchName = sheet.getRange(i,6).getValue();
    launchIdEntry = sheet.getRange(i,col).getValue();
    
    if (launchName != '' && launchIdEntry == ''){
      productName = sheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
      launchIdEntry = productName.substring(0,2).toUpperCase() + Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(10000000)); 
      sheet.getRange(i, col).setValue(launchIdEntry);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Hello there @Mel, can you please provide more details about your task? Specifically, why isn't the solution provided of use to you? You would like to generate the ID if the whole row is pasted but still keep the same old one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [indexOf](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp#:%7E:text=The%20indexOf()%20method%20returns,()%20method%20is%20case%20sensitive.) to see if there your 'searchkey' is in a array of values. If it is not you get a -1 so >= 0 means there is a match. The [].concat[(...arr)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) is to force a 1d array beacause apps script gives a 2d array. Don't know for sure how the indexOf deals with that.

So if the id is in the array of values (col A) then your script will override the value.

The code:

```
function onEdit(evt) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 
  var headerRow = header();
  var rowMax = sheet.getMaxRows();
  var colMax = sheet.getMaxColumns();
  var col = 1; 
  var colNames = sheet.getRange(headerRow, col, 1, colMax).getValues();
  var launchIdEntry = '';
  var launchName = '';
  var productName = '';
  var arr = sheet.getRange(1, 1, rowMax).getValues();
  var uniqueIds = [].concat(...arr);

  for (var i = headerRow + 1; i < rowMax; i++){
    
    launchName = sheet.getRange(i,6).getValue();
    launchIdEntry = sheet.getRange(i,col).getValue();
    
    if (launchName != '' && launchIdEntry == '' || uniqueIds.indexOf(launchIdEntry) >= 0){
      productName = sheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
      launchIdEntry = productName.substring(0,2).toUpperCase() + Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(10000000)); 
      sheet.getRange(i, col).setValue(launchIdEntry);
    }
  }
};
```

**EDIT:**

Okey here is the script i created.

- The OnEdit() checks of column F is not blank IF this is true then the function createID(row) is executed.
- The OnEdit gives the rownumber to the createID
- The DO WHILE loop wil run as long there is no unique id created.

Hope this helps.

```
function onEdit(){
  const row = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getRow();
  const isblank = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 6).getValue();
  
  if (isblank) {
    setID(row);
  };
}

function setID(row) {
  const activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const productName = activeSheet.getRange(row, 4).getValue();
  const allID2d = activeSheet.getRange(2, 1, activeSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const allID = [].concat(...allID2d);
  let newID = "";
  
  do{
    newID = createID(productName);
  } while (allID.indexOf(newID) >= 0);
  
  activeSheet.getRange(row, 1).setValue(newID);
}


function createID(productName){
  return productName.substring(0,2).toUpperCase() + Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(10000000)); 
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

Change the onEdit part to this: (p.s. with google apps script null does not work so you have to do "").

```
function onEdit(){
  const row = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getRow();
  const isblank = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 6).getValue();
  const id = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 1).getValue();
  
  if (isblank  && id == "") {
    setID(row);
  };
}
```

Comment: @rencoE33 this is cool! thanks for the suggestion. I implemented your change in another Script file that now applies to Sheet2 in the spreadsheet I shared. The problem is that it regenerates all the IDs. How can I make existing IDs immutable? Also, for some reason the script is ignoring the condition that column F should be populated in order to add an ID. any suggestions for to fix both things? thanks!

Comment: @rencoE33 this is so amazing. I love how you have simplified the whole thing. One last question. While testing the script I noticed that if I edit the info of an entry, the ID will be regenerated. The goal is that once an ID is created, it should never change again. I was thinking to remove the onEdit, and set a time trigger, but wonder if there's any better way to accomplish this. Maybe just allowing the onEdit when the column 6 ("Title") is edited, but not doing anything if there's already an ID.

Comment: @Mel See my edit2. Hope this is what you are after. If so please solve the topic.

Comment: @rencoE33 sorry for the back and forth, but now seems it won't regenerate an ID if I copy paste an entire row (ie. will keep the duplicated ID copied in the row). I'm thinking maybe is easy to just set a trigger to run the second version of your script every minute.

Comment: Yes that is because the if statement in the onEdit. Why not copy without the id...? If you read the code you will see what is does right...? You want to keep the id the same but if you copy you want it to change. It is possible but dit is not usual and you need to question your question better. P.s. running the second won't do you good if you copy the hole row with id. The if statement still is the same.. so I don't know why you would think so

Comment: @remomcoE33 totally agree and really appreciate your help. For context, I can't control people not copy pasting the whole row including the ID. But I'll use your edit 1 and then make the edit a trigger instead of onEdit. That way it will work perfectly. Thanks for your amazing input and help!

Comment: @rencoE33, actually I'm not using the new App Scripts runtime (and I can't use it in this case), any chance you can edit for compatibility?. I'm getting an error on line 17:   const allID = [].concat(...allID2d);